# ui-router isn't running nested route controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

PLNKR: http://plnkr.co/edit/Or4JTiUrPOJUoW78c8Xd

Hey guys, I'm struggling with an issue that i was able to simplify down to the following sample:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"])
myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/items/123");

    $stateProvider
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: "/items/:itemId",
            templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
            controller: function($scope, $stateParams){
              $scope.itemId = $stateParams.itemId;
            },
            resolve: {
                itemParam: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
                    return $stateParams.itemId;
                }]
            }
        })
        .state('dashboard.history', {
            parent: 'dashboard',
            url: "/history",
            templateUrl: 'dashboard.history.html',
            controller: function($scope, itemParam){
              $scope.itemId = itemParam.itemId;
            }
        });
})
```

dashboard.html

```
<h1>Dashboard for item {{itemId}}</h1>
<a ui-sref="dashboard.history({itemId: 123})">History</a>
```

dashboard.history.html

```
<h1>Dashboard History for item {{itemId}}</h1>
```

The problem is history controller isn't being called and I'm getting no errors. Can anybody explain to me what's up?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you don't have a `<ui-view>` directive inside your parent state:

**[FORKED DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Su5VzCKXQVtpPdVP3fBV?p=preview)**

**dashboard.html**

```
<h1>Dashboard for item {{itemId}}</h1>
<a ui-sref="dashboard.history({itemId: 123})">History</a>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```